# Comment Moderation By Email

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my website project, the following basic process occurs:

1) Someone enters a comment.

2) Comment data is entered as a row into database table.

3) Comment data is sent via PHP mail() function to a Moderator.

Now here is what I'd like to accomplish:

Within the email that the Moderator receives, in addition to the comment data, there will be two buttons. The first button says "Accept Comment". The second says "Deny Comment."

Is it possible, for the Moderator to just click on a button within the email and a function back on the server gets triggered to take care of the rest? Is this an Ajax kind of situation?

Thanks!

Comment: The "buttons" would be links.  Go from there.

Comment: Hey @PatrickQ, thanks for your quick response! But how would the links trigger a function back on the server?

Comment: Because that's what links do, call code on a server.

Comment: you wont be able to make an ajax request out of a mail. So it'll be a link with some params like: `www.example.com/commentAcception.php?accept=true&decline=false&commentId=42&moderatorId=99&securityToken=1234567890abc`

Comment: @Jeff. Thanks!  So are you saying that just by clicking on that link, the script on my server in commentAcception.php starts running? And then I can extract the URL from within that script?

Comment: @PatrickQ Ok, I think I understand! Thanks!

Comment: Yes. All those params will be available as `$_GET['accept']` etc. Make sure to validate those params and to include a long enough security token that is unique for that request and is strickly connected to that one moderator. Remember that _anyone_ can run the script by calling `example.com/commentAcception.php`

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your thorough advice, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add link in the mail which redirect to a special page of your website.

### For example

`www.example.com/acceptComment.php?accept=true&decline=false&commentId=42`

And in the page `acceptComment.php` you should update your database for the comment with id `$_GET["commentId"]`

Comment: @drothhello Great, if it works, you can accept this reply, like this all users can see what works for you. [Learn more about accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)